# Export MS Word tables from many word docs to Excel sheets

Tags: excel, vba, macos, ms-word

I am looking for a script that will extract the table out of every word doc I have in a  folder and place each table result into one workbook/one worksheet in excel. I have too many documents to do them one by one. I also need the file name they were exported from in the final final column (column H/or column 9 assuming the data begins to import starting with column A/or column1)

The code I have found works great if you do each document one at a time but even then it overwrites the previous data in excel when you run it for the next word doc (see below).

(what I use now below - takes me all day to go through one file folder)

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportWordTable()
    Dim wdDoc As Object
    Dim wdFileName As Variant
    Dim tableNo As Integer 'table number in Word
    Dim iRow As Long 'row index in Excel
    Dim iCol As Integer 'column index in Excel
    Dim resultRow As Long
    Dim tableStart As Integer
    Dim tableTot As Integer

    On Error Resume Next


    wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.doc),*.doc", , _
    "Browse for file containing table to be imported")

    If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)

    Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName) 'open Word file

    With wdDoc
        tableNo = wdDoc.tables.count
        tableTot = wdDoc.tables.count
        If tableNo = 0 Then
            MsgBox "This document contains no tables", _
            vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"
        ElseIf tableNo > 1 Then
            tableNo = InputBox("This Word document contains " & tableNo & " tables." & vbCrLf & _
            "Enter the table to start from", "Import Word Table", "1")
        End If

        resultRow = 4

        For tableStart = 1 To tableTot
            With .tables(tableStart)
                'copy cell contents from Word table cells to Excel cells
                For iRow = 1 To .Rows.count
                    For iCol = 1 To .Columns.count
                        Cells(resultRow, iCol) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.Cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text)
                    Next iCol
                    resultRow = resultRow + 1
                Next iRow
            End With
            resultRow = resultRow + 1
        Next tableStart
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `The code I have found works great` Where is your understanding of the code? What have you tried to improve it? Please show us what have you tried? Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: Well, if you're simply rerunning this script for each document, `ActiveSheet.Range("A:AZ").ClearContents` is obviously going to clear what was ever in your existing sheet, and the output logic here does not look for and find the first empty row. Kill that `ClearContents` call and build logic to handle multiple outputs, and that may solve your issue.

Comment: yes, I apologize for not mentioning that you can kill the clear contents but that wont fix the problem. It just stops the clear. It will still overwrite the previous data, as the results are always posted to row four.

Comment: I am looking for the code to loop, and append all the tables into one worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Read [Ron De Bruin's web site](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm) on finding last empty row.

```
Sub ImportWordTable()
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim wdFileName As Variant
Dim tableNo As Integer 'table number in Word
Dim iRow As Long 'row index in Excel
Dim iCol As Integer 'column index in Excel
Dim resultRow As Long
Dim tableStart As Integer
Dim tableTot As Integer

On Error Resume Next

wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.doc),*.doc", , _
"Browse for file containing table to be imported")

If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)

Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName) 'open Word file

With wdDoc
    tableNo = wdDoc.tables.Count
    tableTot = wdDoc.tables.Count
    If tableNo = 0 Then
        MsgBox "This document contains no tables", _
        vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"
    ElseIf tableNo > 1 Then
        tableNo = InputBox("This Word document contains " & tableNo & " tables." & vbCrLf & _
        "Enter the table to start from", "Import Word Table", "1")
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
    Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A4").CurrentRegion
    resultRow = Rng.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=Rng.Cells(1), _
                    Lookat:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Row + 1
    On Error GoTo 0
    If resultRow < 4 Then resultRow = 4

    For tableStart = 1 To tableTot
        With .tables(tableStart)
            'copy cell contents from Word table cells to Excel cells
            For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
                For iCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
                    Cells(resultRow, iCol) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.Cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text)
                Next iCol
                resultRow = resultRow + 1
            Next iRow
        End With
        resultRow = resultRow + 1
    Next tableStart
End With
```

End Sub